# How to improve quality of this answer?

Tags: style, technique, word-choice, reviews

Someone asked on Quora [I want to write my autobiography. How do I start?](http://www.quora.com/I-want-to-write-my-autobiography-How-do-I-start)

I have given following answer,

> You must be remembering lots of things when you were young. Just try
>   to list them as you remember those. Do it for 10-15 days. You will
>   have enough stuff to craft your Childhood journey.
>
> Include memories from friend circle, sports ,hobby or passtime.
>
> Then move ahead to do same thing with your school/college and
>   profession.
>
> Do not forgot to mention what you have learned along the way (Life
>   lessons).
>
> Mention name of people who made you
>
> capable.
>
> Ask your parents or grandparents, they will definitely remember your
>   childhood better than you.

I am not very satisfied with quality of chosen words, and writing style. How should I improve this?

Comment: Critiques like this one are off-topic here, I'm sorry to say. Placing on hold for now, but please feel free to edit this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rewrote your answer with more complicated words and combined a few sentences and now it seems to sound better. I also made the prompts look less like dialogue and more like prompts. Additionally, I dissolved the "(life lessons)" into the sentence it is concerning.

> Try to recall memories from your youth, and write them down as you remember them for 10-15 days. Be sure to include memories of your friends, sports you played, and hobbies you enjoyed.
>
> Do the same for your experiences in school, college, and in your profession. Remember to include important life lessons you have learned and people who capacitated you.
>
> Now ask your parents or grandparents, and you will find that they remember their childhood better than you do.

Comment: I am not a professional, I merely changed the words around until they seemed right, so I cannot guarantee that my advice is sound. I suggest that you wait for somebody more qualified to answer unless the question is urgent.